# NSTimer issue with repeated usage

Tags: ios, nstimer

So I am trying to make a countdown and when its done the game is over. Here is my code:

```
-(void)Movement667{
    loadinglabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Go!"];;

    end =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(Movement999)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

---

```
-(void)Movement999{
    if (gametime > 0){
        gametime = gametime - 1;
        gametimelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gametime];
    }else{
        smallrock6.hidden = YES;
        endlabel.hidden = NO;
        highscore.hidden = NO;
        highscoreannouncer.hidden = NO;
        highscorebackground.hidden = NO;
        highscore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score];
    }
}
```

The first time I play it everything works fine, and it counts down every second. When I play it a second time and so on it starts off normal then it counts down in greater patterns i.e. 2, 4 , 5 ect. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Do you re-init `gametime` the second time?  Also you probably want to invalidate that timer when `gametime <= 0`, and re-create it whenever you re-init `gametime`.  Also `loadinglabel.text = @"Go!";` is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you never stop the timer. So what happens is that when you reset the time and create a new timer there are two timers running at the same time (the selector is called twice per second), then three, four, etc. Try to keep the timer in a property and change the code as follows:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *myTimer;//ADDDED

-(void)Movement667{
    loadinglabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Go!"];;

    self.myTimer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(Movement999)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];//CHANGED
}

-(void)Movement999{
    if (gametime > 0){
        gametime = gametime - 1;
        gametimelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", gametime];
    }else{
        [self.myTimer invalidate];//ADDED
        smallrock6.hidden = YES;
        endlabel.hidden = NO;
        highscore.hidden = NO;
        highscoreannouncer.hidden = NO;
        highscorebackground.hidden = NO;
        highscore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score];
   }
```

}

**ADDED:** If you need to interrupt your game before you run out of time you should make sure to call [self.myTimer invalidate] in that case as well.

**ADDED:** If you want to make sure the timer is also invalidated when your ViewController goes off screen I would suggest invalidate the timer in viewDidDisappear:

```
 -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
     [self.myTimer invalidate];
 }
```

Comment: @Forrest I tried that, but it still does not work. Is it possible it is not cancelling if i leave it before the time is up (like if the int game time (I changed it to end timer) is more than 0)?

Comment: Yes absolutely - in that case you need to call [self.myTimer invalidate] when you leave/interrupt the game.

Comment: Will that involve the app delegate? If so I am a not knowledge in that area so if you could tell me how to do it would be great!

Comment: No it doesn't involve the app delegate. When do you interrupt the game before it runs out of time? When someone wins/lose? Is there a method that you call in that situation? Try to give me move context and I'll try to help.

Comment: Basically, you try to get the best score so when the game ends you see your score (When the timer is up). However if someone were to press the home button or click an in app button to go to the main screen (the app's main screen) during the process of the timer, I would like that to invalidate the int "endtimer". If there an code that you could tell me that activates the invalidation when you leave that view controller (The Mini-Game) it would be great!

Comment: When you go to the main screen do you change View Controller?

Comment: Yes it is a different view controller in the storyboard (sorry for not saying that).

Comment: I updated my answer - try to add the invalidate in the ViewDidDisappear method of the ViewController. This should work in both scenarios.

Comment: Thank you it worked! Will you be able to tell me what the [super viewDidDisappear:animated]; does?

Comment: It's part of the View Controller life cycle - you always need to call the superclass method in order to give the superclass a chance to execute any code. This applies to all the methods of the VC life cycle - viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, etc. I suggest you to have a look at the Apple Documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html)

Answer (score 2):

When the game is done, don't forget to invalidate your time with

```
[end invalidate];
```

Put this code in the else statement in Movement999.
It stops the receiver from ever firing again. And then you can restart the timer for a new game.